# How to avoid z-fighting in OpenGL when drawing both the mesh surface and the polygon edges?

Tags: opengl

Consider the following image:

[image]

It has both the mesh surface and the polygon edges visualized. What's more, even though the edges and the faces should have the same z-coordinates on the places where they are drawn and cause [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), in this image, the polygon edges are always visible as long as they are not covered by a (non-adjacent) polygon, and there is no visible z-fighting. How can this be achieved in OpenGL?

Comment: [The usual `glPolygonOffset()` method](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm) not working for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault How do you use it in this case? I can't find any pedagogic demonstration or documentation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just enable some MSAA on the frame buffer I'm rendering to, and then just do:

```cpp
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
drawShadededMesh();

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
drawWireMesh();
```

That usually works well enough in most cases. Failing that(as mentioned in the comments) you can experiment with glPolygonOffset.

```cpp
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0); ///< may need adjustment for your use case
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
drawShadededMesh();
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
drawWireMesh();
```

Comment: Thanks; your second piece of code did the trick!